# JBOSS_7.1EAP Error "Services with missing/ unavailable dependencies"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I am trying to deploy an ear file which contains a war file and an ejb jar file in Jboss 7.1 EAP server. But I am getting the following error when I am trying to start the server with *standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml*

```
18:10:11,546 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "icam-e.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "module.resolved.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main",
        "module.resolved.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icam-e-web-1.war\".main",
        "jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main",
        "module.resolved.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear\".main"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear\".main]",
        "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.icam-e.ear\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main]",
        "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main]",
        "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icam-e-web-1.war\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main]",
        "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"
eployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main]",
        "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icam-e-web-1.war\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.icam-e.ear.icamEJB-0.0.1.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"d
ployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icam-e-web-1.war\".main]"
    ]
}
18:10:11,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "icam-e.ear" (runtime-name : "icam-e.ear")
18:10:11,572 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.icam-e.ear.icamEJB-0.0.1.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.icam-e.ear".main, service jboss.module.resolve.phase."dep
oyment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icamEJB-0.0.1.jar".main.1, service jboss.module.service."deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icamEJB-0.0.1.jar".main, service jboss.module.resolve.phase."deployment.icam-e.ea
.com.ge.digital-icam-e-web-1.war".main.1, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 3 more ]
      service module.resolved.service."deployment.icam-e.ear".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.icam-e.ear".main]
      service module.resolved.service."deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icam-e-web-1.war".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icam-e-web-1.war".m
in]
      service module.resolved.service."deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icamEJB-0.0.1.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.icam-e.ear.com.ge.digital-icamEJB-0.0.1.jar"
main]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above suggests that the EAR file has not been deployed successfully. Try killing the server and deleting the "jboss directory/standalone/tmp" and "jboss directory/standalone/data" before redeploying . If that too fails ,Please attach full log file and standalone-full.xml file.